# Android performance between activities

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I have been looking for a simpler way to speed up my app performance. I am not new but I am not a real experienced android programmer so I want to look for something easily implementable that will help my app perform better. As of now I use flags from the Intent class and have looked up other solutions but most of what I have found online is either very complicated or does not make a real impact on my app's performance. All help and suggestions are welcome, thank you.

Comment: Um, performance isn't something you sprinkle into an app. You start by determining where your performance problem lies and what the cause is. Then, you look for a targeted solution to whatever that specific problem is. There is [a lot of documentation on this](http://developer.android.com/tools/performance/index.html), though some is written with Eclipse in mind instead of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to have any benefit in performance by using frags. If I were you I would try making the instantiation of the target activity as quick as possible. Do *not* do any hard work on the main thread, which will result slowing down the creation of the new activity.

Also, you can modify the enter animation of the new activity so that the user doesn't have to wait as long for it to be interactable. This can be tricky to get right though design wise.